# Verifying Digital Signature when retrieving the certificate from the database

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I am experiencing a very strange issue that I simply can't understand why it is happening.

I have a client and a server.  The two applications communicate through a SOAP web service.  Now, before being able to communicate with the server, the client must register on the server's website and upload a digital certificate.  The server saves the digital certificate in the database.

When the client makes the web service call, he sends the details along with a digital signature of the details concatenated together using the private key of the digital certificate that he uploaded on the vendor's website.

The client then sends the details and the digital signature to the server.  The server identifies the client, retrieves his certificate from the database and extracts the public key in order to verify the digital signature.

One strange thing is that the public key on both sides is exactly the same.

Another strange thing is that when, on the server, I change the code in such a way that, instead of retrieving the certificate from the database, I retrieve it from the certificate store (exactly like I did in the client), the digital signature matches correctly.

I really don't know what's wrong.  Can someone help please?  I would appreciate it immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and desperation, I finally found out what the problem was.  When I was loading the certificate from the database, apparently it was not allowing the program to access the public key.

For this reason, I added a column in my table for the public key and extracted the public key during the sign up process and saved it as an XML String like this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
string public_key = csp.ToXMLString(false); //to store public key only
```

Then I saved it in the database.  In order to verify the signature, I load the key from the database and passed it to csp as follows:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.FromXMLString(public_key);
```

I hope that this answer helps someone as it was very difficult to trace the problem for me and I wasted a lot of time.